# Swift 3 class generics - T conform to class and protocol

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

I’m writing a subclass of `NSOperation` using generics that looks like this:

```
class FetchManagedObjectOperation<T: NSManagedObject, NSFetchRequestResult>: Operation { }
```

Inside the operation I create a fetch request like so:

```
let objectRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> to specified type NSFetchRequest<T>.
```

This suggests that `T` is only of type `NSManagedObject`.

There’s an Xcode fix-it but it suggests this:

```
let objectRequest: NSFetchRequest<T> = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
```

Which causes a crash as `objectRequest` is null at runtime.

Comment: Please show how you instantiate `FetchManagedObjectOperation`.

Comment: `let operation = FetchManagedObjectOperation<MyRecord>` where MyRecord is a subclass of NSManagedObject.

Comment: That is not an instantiation. Maybe update the question the the exact code you are using.

Comment: My bad, I was on my phone… `let operation = FetchManagedObjectOperation<MyRecord>()`